# Which .travis.yml is used when building PRs?

Tags: build, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I am new to travis and I am struggling to understand something. When using a pull-request workflow, I am not sure *which* `.travis.yml` is used by the system: the one on the upstream branch, or the one from the fork?

Initially, I thought that it should be the one on the upstream branch. When I create a repo and invite contributions, then I am setting the rules to accept them. I am reviewing the changes and accepting/rejecting PRs. Therefore, I find it logical that I create a `.travis.yml` and that this one is used to annotate the PR in GitHub.

From what I have observed so far, it is not the case. It seems that a user forking my repo can change the `.travis.yml` file and that it is this modified version that is used when building the PR.

If that is the case, then it means that a contributor could for instance change the `.travis.yml` to disable automated tests. It also means that when I review a PR, I must be careful to check whether `.travis.yml` has been modified or not (and whether this is legit).

I do understand the need for a PR to sometimes modify the travis configuration (for instance, if my contribution is to introduce a new test framework in the project).

I was unable to find comprehensive documentation and best practices on the topic, so I would appreciate feedback and ideas very much.

Comment: It is the `.travis.yml` in the branch of the PR (don't limit it to just forks since PRs can come from upstream branches too). It doesn't require being careful to check that the file was modified though, since both Github and Gitlab make it super easy to immediately see what was changed and where during a PR, and you would see that unless you blindly accept the PR.

Comment: Ok, thanks @MattSchuchard, I agree that it is usually easy to spot modifications made to .travis.yml. But the most important was to get a confirmation of the behaviour, so thank you.